# program ignores everything after function is called

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I can't even explaing it properly..
So I have code like

```
printf_s("%s", "1");
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.IndCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0); 
printf_s("%s", "2");
eglSwapBuffers ( esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface);
```

And 2 is never printed
.When i remove glDrawElements it's all ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.IndCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ whaaaaat?
```

OpenGL ES' [`glDrawElements()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) does not accept `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for `type`, just `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` or `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

If you check `glGetError()` after that call you should get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

Comment: Thanks that was it
But I still don't get it, why it just exited function?

Answer (score 0):

Try `printf` instead of `printf_s` (which will stop printing if any of it's constraints are violated -- which may very well be what `glDrawElements` is doing) and flush `stdout` after each print.

Answer (score 0):

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.IndCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
```

crashes, so next statements are never executed.

give a correct 4th parameter to glDrawElements to fix your crash.

Comment: Actually, if there's OpenGL Buffer Object bound on the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER target, that parameter is perfectly valid. However without an element array being bound it's of course wrong.